# How to converted imported .txt string data into float type?

Tags: python, string

I was importing a .txt file into Python,I know their type is string, but when I tried to convert them into float, there is an error reported. Could any one tell me what's happening here?

```
with open('datatest.txt') as file_object:
    contents = file_object.read()
    print(contents)
display(type(contents))
contents = float(contents)

100
60
70
900
100
200
500
500

str
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-659198854b7d> in <module>
      3     print(contents)
      4 display(type(contents))
----> 5 contents = float(contents)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '100\n60\n70\n900\n100\n200\n500\n500\n'
```

Comment: You trying convert to float string with many numbers delimited by `\n` symbol.
You need reed file line by line and convert each line to float separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading in the entire text file as a string, so it has the end line characters `\n` after each number which cannot be converted to a float. You could try this

```
[float(a) for a in content[:-2].split('\n')]
```

This splits the string by `\n` and then converts each string into a float ([:-2] gets rid of the last end line).

Alternatively you could read line by line, like so

```
contents = []
with open('datatest.txt') as file_object:
    for line in file_object
        contents.append(float(line))
print(contents)
```

Comment: Thanks, very good answer! Could you show me in details of 'contents[:-2]', what does it look like? I am confused see it. Shouldn't it be 'content.split('\n')[:-1]'

Comment: Those both work. `contents[:-2]` removes the last two characters of the string which are `\` and `n`. `content.split('\n')[:-1]` removes the empty last element after splitting. Either works, they are functionally the same.

Comment: See some of the other answers, they deal with this issue a bit better by using strip. Or I would recommend using the line by line solution presented below, it is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You might use readlines to get this task done following way:

```
with open('datatest.txt') as file_object:
    contents = file_object.readlines()
contents = [float(i.strip()) for i in contents if i.strip()]
```

`readlines` return list of lines, with trailing newlines (`\n`). I use `.strip()` to remove them and also check if line is not empty str (`if i.strip()`) to prevent loading `''` into `float`, which would cause error.

Answer (score 0):

This could also work:

```
with open('dataset.txt') as file_object:
    lines_raw = file_object.readlines()

lines = [line.strip() for line in lines_raw]
contents = [float(number) for number in lines]
```